# Submit does not carry out function onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, function, submit, onsubmit

I'm expecting the submit button to carry out the function checker() however it is not working at all, no alert, am I doing something wrong?

It should be I press submit and the checker goes on, it then gets a true or false if the email field is correct.  if it is true, a popup div appears.

alternatively all I want to do is submit the form which was working using:

```
<form action="<?php echo $website.$relative_string;?>" name="subscribe" onsubmit="javascript:return checkEmail(this);" method="post">
```

After it has been submitted, I wall to call the function popupClick();

Thanks Chris

```
<?php include("globals.php"); ?>   
<script>
var sub = document.getElementById('sub');
var unsub = document.getElementById('unsub');
var btn = document.getElementById('submitButton2');

jQuery(function($) {

$("a.topopup").click(function() {
        loading(); // loading
        setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
            loadPopup(); // function show popup 
        }, 500); // .5 second
return false;
});

/* event for close the popup */
$("div.close").hover(
                function() {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').show();
                },
                function () {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').hide();
                }
            );

$("div.close").click(function() {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});

$(this).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    }   
});

$("div#backgroundPopup").click(function() {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});

function popupClick() {
    loading(); // loading
    setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
        loadPopup(); // function show popup 
    }, 500); // .5 second
}

/************** start: functions. **************/
function loading() {
    $("div.loader").show();  
}
function closeloading() {
    $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');  
}

var popupStatus = 0; // set value

function loadPopup() { 
    if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
        closeloading(); // fadeout loading
        $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
        $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001); 
        popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
    }   
}

function disablePopup() {
    if(popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup
        $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
        popupStatus = 0;  // and set value to 0
    }
}
/************** end: functions. **************/

sub.onchange = function() //When sub changes
{
if(sub.checked)  //If it's checked
{
    btn.innerHTML = "<span>Join</span>";
}
else // If not..
{
    btn.innerHTML = "<span>Leave</span>";
}
}

unsub.onchange = function() //When unsub changes
{
if(unsub.checked)  //If it's checked
{
    btn.innerHTML = "<span>Leave</span>";
}
else // If not..
{
    btn.innerHTML = "<span>Join</span>";
}
}

function checker()
{
window.alert("checker function");
if (checkEmail(this) = true)
  {
    window.alert("email correct");
    popupClick();
    return true;
  }
elseif
{
   window.alert("email check wrong");
   return false;
}
}

}); // jQuery End
</script>

<form action="<?php echo $website.$relative_string;?>" name="subscribe" onsubmit="return checker();" method="post">
  <div id="cell8" class="titlecell2"><h3>Email:</h3></div>
     <div id="cell9" class="inputcell2">
        <input type="text" class="inputfield2" name="email" value="Your Email..." id="email2" maxlength="255" onfocus="this.value='';">
     </div>
     <div id="cell10" class="textcell3">
       <input name="group" type="hidden" id="group[]" value="<?php echo $group; ?>">
       <input name="subscribe" id="sub" type="radio" value="true" checked>
       </span>Subscribe</p>
     </div>
     <div id="cell11" class="buttoncell">
        <button type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Join" id="submitButton2" button" onClick="javascript:myFunction();"/>
        <span>Join</span>
        </button>
     </div>
     <div id="cell8" class="textcell4">
       <input type="radio" name="subscribe" id="unsub" value="false">
       </span>Un-Subscribe</p>
     </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has lots of problems. Fix all these, then try again:

- `onClick="javascript:myFunction();"` is wrong. The quoted string needs to be Javascript code, so `javascript:` does not belong there. You are confusing this with `<a href="javascript:...`.  You want `onclick="myFunction()"`
- You have self-closing button tags: `<button ... />Join</button>` where the `/>` closes the tag immediately, so that it does not enclose the "Join" text that follows. This means if you click on Join, it is not associated with the button, so nothing will happen.  Your editor should have flagged that as an error.
- You have `</span>Subscribe</p>` where no span or paragraph were previously opened. You need to use an editor that can highlight that. If Visual Studio is overkill, I recommend Microsoft's free Expression Web. (I use it a lot.)
- In your checker() function, the `if` condition contains the `=` assignment operator. You need to use the `==` comparison operator.
- You don't need to use `== true` in a condition.  Instead of `if ( blah == true )` just use `if ( blah )`.   There are advanced cases where you might want to use `=== true` where `===` means "is identical to", but that doesn't apply here.
- In your checker() function, `elseif` should be simply `else` since you are not testing another condition.
- In your checker() function, `checkEmail(this)` won't work because checker() is not being invoked as a method of an object, therefore `this` is not defined.  `onsubmit="return checker()"` actually defines an anonymous method function containing `return checker()` as the function body. The simplest fix for this is to pass `this` as an argument to the checker() function, like this:

  ```
  function checker(theForm) {
      if ( checkEmail(theForm) ) {
          ...

  <form onsubmit="return checker(this)" ...>
  ```